# Trying to sort out available online training courses for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, training

I tried to contact many training centres in Jordan (where I live) but all of them currently only provide class room training courses for SharePoint 2010. And as I need to start a new SP project using version 2013, so I think the best thing to go with is to find an online training courses (free OR Paid) to attend. I find these two links but not sure if they are sufficient to do a complete implementation for an internal & external SharePoint web application.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123633.aspx

**&**

1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/fp123606

So can any one advice of other online training courses for SP2013.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a great collection for you:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/07/17/sharepoint-2013-early-training-amp-resources-for-it-pros-now-available.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2012/07/17/sharepoint-2013-it-pro-and-developer-training-materials-released.aspx

http://sharepoint-videos.com/sharepoint-2013-video-tutorials/